# Getting string from an int input

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I need to get the values as strings. How do I do this? In the first set of directions I was given seven numbers as integers. So I set all the variables up as integers besides players, but I also want to get all values as strings.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Baseball {

public static void main(String[] args) {    
    //opens a new scanner instance
    Scanner baseball = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Allows a person to enter players name
    System.out.print("Enter the Players Name: ");
    // reads the users entry and assigns it the String "players"
    String players = baseball.nextLine();

    // Allows a person to enter the amount of at bats
    System.out.print("Enter the amount of at bats: ");
    // reads the users entry and assigns it the int "atBats"
    int atBats = baseball.nextInt();

    // Allows a person to enter home runs
    System.out.print("Enter the amount of homeruns: ");
    // reads the users entry and assigns it the int "homeruns"
    int homeruns = baseball.nextInt();

    // Allows a person to enter walks
    System.out.print("Enter the amount of walks: ");
    // reads the users entry and assigns it the int "walks"
    int walks = baseball.nextInt();

    // Allows a person to enter Doubles
    System.out.print("Enter the amount of doubles: ");
    // reads the users entry and assigns it the int "doubles"
    int doubles = baseball.nextInt();

    // Allows a person to enter Triples
    System.out.print("Enter the amount of triples: ");
    int triples = baseball.nextInt();

    // Allows a person to enter hits
    System.out.print("Enter the amount of hits: ");
    int hits = baseball.nextInt();

    baseball.close();

    //calculates singles
    int singles = (hits - homeruns - doubles - triples);

    battingAverage(hits, atBats);
    onBasePercentage(hits, atBats, walks);
    sluggingPercentage(singles, doubles, triples, homeruns, atBats);
}
//method that calculates battingAverage
public static void battingAverage(int hits, int atBats) {
    Double average = (double) (hits / atBats);
    System.out.println("The batting average is: " + average);
}
//method that calculates onBasePercentage
public static void onBasePercentage(int hits, int atBats, int walks) {
    Double basePercentage = (double) (hits + walks) / (atBats + walks);
    System.out.println("The on base percentage is: " + basePercentage);

}
//method that calculates sluggingPercentage
public static void sluggingPercentage(int singles, int doubles,int triples, int homeruns, int atBats) {
     Double slugPercentage = (double) (singles + 2 * doubles + 3 * triples + 4 * homeruns)/ atBats;
    System.out.println("The slugging percentage is: " + slugPercentage);
}
}
```

Comment: Without looking at your code, but only reading the top part of your question, you might be looking for something like `String.valueOf(someInt)`. This way you can accept input as ints, but then convert them to strings.

Comment: just use `baseball.next()`

Comment: azurefrog- it erros out because all of my variables are ints I would have to change them to strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Integer.toString(int);` There is a class representing each primitive type. They contain tools. If you must grab them as Strings and convert to int:

Switch your scanner from `nextInt()` to `next()`, and use `Integer.parseInt(string);`

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use

```
int yourValue;
String yourStringFromTheValue = yourValue+"";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just do the following: String str = theint + "";

or baseball.next() to get the string from Scanner

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
 int val = 3 ; 
 String myStrVal = Integer.toString(val);
```

Similarly for double values you can use :

```
  double dVal = 3.4;
  String myStrVal = Double.toString(dVal);
```